# How to draw a cylinder in prism?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw cylinder like this picture
[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,backgrounds,patterns}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    \def\a{2.5}
    \def\h{2*\a}
    \def\r{\a*sqrt(3)/6}
        \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\a,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/2});
    \coordinate (O) at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/6});
    \coordinate (M) at ($ (A) !0.5!(B) $);
    \coordinate (N) at ($ (C) !0.5!(A) $);
    
    \draw[dashed] (O) circle (\r);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\h]
    \coordinate (A') at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B') at (\a,0);
    \coordinate (C') at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/2});
        \coordinate (O') at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/6});
        \draw[thick] (O') circle (\r);
        \coordinate (M') at ($ (A') !0.5!(B') $);
        \coordinate (N') at ($ (C') !0.5!(A') $);
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \v/\position in {A/left,B/below,C/right,O/below,A'/above,B'/left,C'/right} {\draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }

\draw[thick] (A') -- (B') -- (C') -- cycle
(B) -- (C)  (B) --(B') (C)-- (C') 
;

\draw[dashed]  (A) -- (A') (B) -- (A) -- (C) (O) -- (O') (N) -- (N') (M) -- (M');
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

The cylinder incorrect. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometrically the end points of the vertical lines are the intersections of a horizontal line *on the screen* and the respective circles. These points are called `b1`, `b2`, `t1` and `t2` in the code. `overlay` is used to make sure that the auxiliary paths do not alter the bounding box.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    \def\a{2.5}
    \def\h{2*\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{\a*sqrt(3)/6}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \path[tdplot_screen_coords,overlay] 
        (-3*\r,0) coordinate (Xm) (3*\r,0) coordinate (Xp);
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
     \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
     \coordinate (B) at (\a,0);
     \coordinate (C) at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/2});
     \coordinate (O) at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/6});
     \coordinate (M) at ($ (A) !0.5!(B) $);
     \coordinate (N) at ($ (C) !0.5!(A) $);
     \draw[dashed,name path=circle] (O) circle (\r);
     \path[overlay,name path=hori] ($(O)-0.5*($(Xp)-(Xm)$)$) -- ++ ($(Xp)-(Xm)$);
     \path[name intersections={of=circle and hori,by={b1,b2}}];
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\h]
    \coordinate (A') at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B') at (\a,0);
    \coordinate (C') at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/2});
        \coordinate (O') at (\a/2,{\a*sqrt(3)/6});
        \path[name path=circle] (O') circle (\r);
        \path[overlay,name path=hori] ($(O')-0.5*($(Xp)-(Xm)$)$) -- ++ ($(Xp)-(Xm)$);
        \path[name intersections={of=circle and hori,by={t1,t2}}];
        \draw[dashed,thick] (b1) -- (t1) (b2) -- (t2);
        \draw[thick] (O') circle (\r);
        \coordinate (M') at ($ (A') !0.5!(B') $);
        \coordinate (N') at ($ (C') !0.5!(A') $);
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \v/\position in {A/left,B/below,C/right,O/below,A'/above,B'/left,C'/right} {\draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }

\draw[thick] (A') -- (B') -- (C') -- cycle
(B) -- (C)  (B) --(B') (C)-- (C') 
;

\draw[dashed]  (A) -- (A') (B) -- (A) -- (C) (O) -- (O');
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can they put at `(\tdplotmainphi:\r)` and `(\tdplotmainphi-180:\r)`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Yes, that's probably a good idea. Note, however, that the above works also in rotated coordinates, so it is perhaps somewhat more "failsafe".

Comment: Please try with `\def\a{2.5}
    \def\h{\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{\a*sqrt(3)/6}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{100}`

Vetical right dashed line is not nice.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I think the edges are still correct but the dash pattern is a bit unfortunate in that case. Try e.g. `\draw[densely dashed] (b1) -- (t1) (b2) -- (t2);`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to marmot for [this answer](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1732). With this answer, I tried

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \foreach \Angle in {5,15,...,355}  
    {
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=\Angle,psi=0,theta=70},line join = round, line cap = round,same bounding box=A,declare function={a=3;b=4;h=4;}]
            \path (0,0,0) coordinate (A)
            (a,0,0) coordinate (B) (0,b,0) coordinate (C)
        (0,0,h) coordinate (A')
        (a,0,h) coordinate (B') (0,b,h) coordinate (C') 
        (1,1,h/2) coordinate (O'');
\path pic[red,3d/hidden]{3d incircle={% 
        A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(C)},center name=I}}
 pic[blue,3d/visible]{3d incircle={% 
            A={(A')},B={(B')},C={(C')},center name=I'}};    
        \tikzset{3d/polyhedron/.cd,O={(O'')},
            fore/.append style={fill=none,/tikz/3d/visible}, 
            back/.append style={fill=none,/tikz/3d/hidden},
            draw face with corners={{(A)},{(B)},{(B')},{(A')}},
            draw face with corners={{(B)},{(C)},{(C')},{(B')}},
            draw face with corners={{(C)},{(A)},{(A')},{(C')}},
            draw face with corners={{(A')},{(B')},{(C')}}} 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myr}{tddistance("(I')","(tmppa)")}
        \draw[3d/hidden] 
    ([xshift=-\myr*1cm]I) -- ([xshift=-\myr*1cm]I')
    ([xshift=\myr*1cm]I) -- ([xshift=\myr*1cm]I');
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]